# Automatic jquery effects (not wanted)

Tags: jquery, hide, show, jquery-effects

I've created a simple show/hide menu : when you click on one button the current tab hides and another one shows up. I've set the `'fade'` effect but some slides and other effects are happening. Here's the example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/wydmae/pen/VWgLWb). I'd like to apply something other than fade but for now to solve the problem I put this. I don't know why it's doing this. Can anyone help? :) Thanks!

```js
// Tab function
$(".titab.home").click(function() {
  $(".tab").hide("fade");
  $(".tab.home").show("fade");
});
$(".titab.contact").click(function() {
  $(".tab").hide("fade");
  $(".tab.contact").show("fade");
});
$(".titab.submit").click(function() {
  $(".tab").hide("fade");
  $(".tab.submit").show("fade");
});
$(".titab.links").click(function() {
  $(".tab").hide("fade");
  $(".tab.links").show("fade");
});
```

```css
/*edit scrollbar*/

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height:auto;
    background-color:#6b6d6d;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height:4px;
    width:3px;
    padding-right:2px;
    background-color:white;
}


#s-m-t-tooltip {
    max-width:300px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 6px;
    margin:20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color:#6b6d6d;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:9px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:99999999;
}

 
body {
    background:#eee;
    margin:0px;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:100%;
}
   
/*edit links*/

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
    -moz-outline-style:none;
    color:#000000;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.8s;
}
 
/*edit link hover*/

a:hover {
    color:#ddd;
    outline:none;
    -moz-outline-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
img {
    border:none;
}
 
blockquote {
    padding-left:5px;
    border-left:2px solid #000000;
 
}
 
blockquote blockquote {
    padding-left:5px;
    border-left:2px solid;
}
 
h1 {
    font-size:8px;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:arial;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#000000;
}
 
h2 {
    font-size:8px;
    font-family:arial;
    text-align:left;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#000000;
}


#topbar {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 80px;
  position:fixed;
  background: black;
}


#title {
  color:#fff;
  font-family: 'Unica One';
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding-left: 10px;
} 

.tabs {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-194.5px;
  width:389px;
  height:100%;
}
.titab{
  cursor: pointer;
  background:white;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.titab:first-of-type {
  margin-left:0;
}
.tab {
  display:none;
}
.tab iframe{
  margin-top:100px;
  width:400px;
}
.link {
  width:100px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.tilink{
  background:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:15px;
  border:1px solid #888;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
}
.link a{
  display:block;
  background:#fff;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  border-top:none;
}
 
 
.entries {
    padding:20px;
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}
 
.post {
    width:500px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
 
 
/* POST INFO */ 

.postinfo {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    margin-left:-12px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    width:500px;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:arial;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    font-size:10px;
   
    }
 
.postinfo a {
    color:#000000;
    }
   
.postinfo a:hover {
    color:#ddd;
    }
   
/*tags*/ 

.tags {
    width:500px;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-left:-3px;
    padding:2px;
    font-family:arial;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:left;
     
    }
   
.tags a {
    color:#000000;
    }
   
.tags a:hover {
    color:#ddd;
    }
   
.postnote {
    width:500px;
    margin-top:40px;
    font-family:arial;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    font-style:normal;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:left;
  }
   
/*asks*/  

#question {
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:none;
    font-family:arial;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;    
    padding-left:9px;
    background:#fff;
    color:#000 ;
   
}
 
#question a{
    color:#000;
   
}
 

 
/*audio player container*/ 

.playercontainer {
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:0px;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:480px;
}

/*artist, song, etc.*/ 

.musicinfo {
    padding-top:7px;
    padding-left:50px;
    color:#000;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>THEMES</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://assets.tumblr.com/images/default_avatar/sphere_closed_128.png">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/rss">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unica+One" rel="stylesheet">



  <div id="topbar">
    <div id="title">Themes for you</div>

    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="titab home">Home</div>
      <div class="titab contact">Contact</div>
      <div class="titab submit">Submit</div>
      <div class="titab links">Links</div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="tab home">
    <div class="entries">
      <div class="post">


        <iframe width="500" height="281" id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LKn_3jOKCd8?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        <p>Video example</p>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913245268/video-example">5:17 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/video-post">#video post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">


        <iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F4595620&amp;visual=true&amp;liking=false&amp;sharing=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;continuous_play=false&amp;origin=tumblr" frameborder="0"
          allowtransparency="true" class="soundcloud_audio_player" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
        <p>Song example</p>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913201693/song-example">5:16 pm</a>       <a href="http://soundcloud.com/rodrigovaz/johann-sebastian-bach-pachelbels-cannon-in-d-major">source</a></div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/song-post">#song post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">


        <h1>Chat example</h1><b>Someone:</b> Hello!<br><b>Somebody:</b> How are you?<br><b>Someone:</b> Good. This is an example of a chat between two people<br>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913135663/chat-example">5:14 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/chat-post">#chat post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">


        <h1><a href="http://t.umblr.com/redirect?z=http%3A%2F%2Ffr.lipsum.com%2F&amp;t=NzM2ZDBmOWE1MjkxNjE3ZWE4MTVjZWY0YjhkMmYwYzA5MzFlMTcxOSxXMUV1V2RJNg%3D%3D&amp;b=t%3Aug0c1iN6GrzkGIMg-nJ8Ww&amp;p=https%3A%2F%2Fthemesforyou.tumblr.com%2Fpost%2F162913065653%2Florem-ipsum-all-the-facts-lipsum-generator&amp;m=1">Lorem Ipsum - All the facts - Lipsum generator</a></h1>
        <p>Link example</p>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913065653/lorem-ipsum-all-the-facts-lipsum-generator">5:12 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/link-post">#link post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">


        <big><b>"This is what a quote looks like"</b></big>
        <p></p>— Source


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913036513/this-is-what-a-quote-looks-like">5:11 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/quote-post">#quote post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">


        <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/image/162913004603"><img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/cf975a46b1a6b0183ea6e5017f56271c/tumblr_oszxhlV6bZ1wuevxyo1_500.png"></a>
        <p>Photo example</p>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913004603/photo-example">5:10 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/photo-post">#photo post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">

        <h1><big><big>Text example</big></big></h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur eget massa at mattis. Nulla ullamcorper massa ante, et bibendum sem ultricies et. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse tempus orci ex, fermentum accumsan velit pulvinar
          a. Pellentesque vehicula, felis non fermentum suscipit, sem velit scelerisque urna, eu placerat velit lectus ut metus. Duis molestie scelerisque convallis. In ornare libero ipsum, eget rhoncus velit viverra a. Maecenas facilisis tellus metus,
          ac consequat tellus tristique et. Aenean eu neque eu erat euismod euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis in maximus ipsum.</p>
        <p>Nullam ac dui et augue rhoncus condimentum facilisis in orci. Aenean sit amet metus magna. Mauris eu pellentesque velit. Nullam dui risus, varius nec sem pellentesque, suscipit consequat mauris. Vivamus volutpat, mi in molestie blandit, ligula
          odio efficitur libero, ac porta leo tellus eu felis. Mauris auctor orci sagittis libero semper tristique. Praesent hendrerit purus ex, eget fermentum nulla maximus nec. Fusce nisi metus, scelerisque et mi vitae, posuere condimentum odio. Aenean
          maximus erat non commodo aliquam. Aliquam ac tincidunt metus. Integer tincidunt id sapien lobortis imperdiet. Maecenas enim sem, vehicula sit amet feugiat sit amet, ornare vitae ex. Nam vulputate volutpat quam, a dapibus justo cursus vel. Donec
          ac gravida nulla. In ultrices erat et dictum tristique.</p>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162912904188/text-example">5:07 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/text-post">#text post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/example-post">#example post</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <!-- end entries-->

  </div>
  <!--end tab 1-->

  <div class="tab contact">

    <iframe class="inbox" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="no" width="350" height="260" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.tumblr.com/ask_form/themesforyou.tumblr.com"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="tab submit">
    <iframe class="inbox" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="no" width="350" height="260" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.tumblr.com/submit_form/themesforyou.tumblr.com"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="tab links">
    <div class="link">
      <div class="tilink">Title</div>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 1</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 2</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 3</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
      <div class="tilink">Title</div>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 1</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 2</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 3</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
      <div class="tilink">Title</div>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 1</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 2</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 3</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: The issue is due to the `height` and `width` of the tab being animated due to the `fade`. What effect are you looking to achieve instead?

Comment: I've put your Pen into a snippit for you ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45088602/edit) the page to see how). I also used CodePen's *tidy* tool to correctly indent the source before pasting it here, which makes it much more readable. Note also that jQuery 1.7 is *very* old, consider upgrading to 3.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm not sure what you mean, but if I could just make the fade work for now just to be sure the effect works properly

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hide/ from the API it looks like the jQuery functions `show` and `hide` take a duration and not an effect.

Comment: @Steve I see.. But even if I put, say, the slide effect on each of them, it does the same thing (I've updated the codepen)

Comment: Point is, the function show and hide don't take an effect as a parameter.  Passing the effect as you are doing is causing show and hide to "puke"

Comment: On this page though https://jqueryui.com/show/ there are effects @Steve

Comment: You are not using `jqueryui`. You would need to import that library....

Answer (score 1):

From additional comments it is clear you are attempting to use an extension to `show` and `hide` from [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/).  Importing that library will allow your original code to function as expected.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you review the API documentation for [show](http://api.jqueryui.com/show/) in jQueryUI you will see the following quote;

> This plugin extends jQuery's built-in .show() method. If jQuery UI is not loaded, calling the .show() method may not fail directly, as the method still exists. However, the expected behavior will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `hide` and `show` do not take the parameters you are are passing, the default animation is occuring.  Consider using `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` for your purposes.

https://api.jquery.com/hide/

https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[title]").style_my_tooltips({
      tip_follows_cursor: true,

      tip_delay_time: 50,

      tip_fade_speed: 600,

      attribute: "title"
    });
  });
})(jQuery);

// Tab function
$(".titab.home").click(function() {
  $(".tab").fadeOut();
  $(".tab.home").fadeIn();
});
$(".titab.contact").click(function() {
  $(".tab").fadeOut();
  $(".tab.contact").fadeIn();
});
$(".titab.submit").click(function() {
  $(".tab").fadeOut();
  $(".tab.submit").fadeIn();
});
$(".titab.links").click(function() {
  $(".tab").fadeOut();
  $(".tab.links").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
/*edit scrollbar*/

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height:auto;
    background-color:#6b6d6d;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height:4px;
    width:3px;
    padding-right:2px;
    background-color:white;
}


#s-m-t-tooltip {
    max-width:300px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 6px;
    margin:20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color:#6b6d6d;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:9px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:99999999;
}

 
body {
    background:#eee;
    margin:0px;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:100%;
}
   
/*edit links*/

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
    -moz-outline-style:none;
    color:#000000;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration:0.8s;
}
 
/*edit link hover*/

a:hover {
    color:#ddd;
    outline:none;
    -moz-outline-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
img {
    border:none;
}
 
blockquote {
    padding-left:5px;
    border-left:2px solid #000000;
 
}
 
blockquote blockquote {
    padding-left:5px;
    border-left:2px solid;
}
 
h1 {
    font-size:8px;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:arial;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#000000;
}
 
h2 {
    font-size:8px;
    font-family:arial;
    text-align:left;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#000000;
}


#topbar {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 80px;
  position:fixed;
  background: black;
}


#title {
  color:#fff;
  font-family: 'Unica One';
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding-left: 10px;
} 

.tabs {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-194.5px;
  width:389px;
  height:100%;
}
.titab{
  cursor: pointer;
  background:white;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.titab:first-of-type {
  margin-left:0;
}
.tab {
  display:none;
}
.tab iframe{
  margin-top:100px;
  width:400px;
}
.link {
  width:100px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.tilink{
  background:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:15px;
  border:1px solid #888;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
}
.link a{
  display:block;
  background:#fff;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  border-top:none;
}
 
 
.entries {
    padding:20px;
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}
 
.post {
    width:500px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
 
 
/* POST INFO */ 

.postinfo {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    margin-left:-12px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    width:500px;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:arial;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    font-size:10px;
   
    }
 
.postinfo a {
    color:#000000;
    }
   
.postinfo a:hover {
    color:#ddd;
    }
   
/*tags*/ 

.tags {
    width:500px;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-left:-3px;
    padding:2px;
    font-family:arial;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:left;
     
    }
   
.tags a {
    color:#000000;
    }
   
.tags a:hover {
    color:#ddd;
    }
   
.postnote {
    width:500px;
    margin-top:40px;
    font-family:arial;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    font-style:normal;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:left;
  }
   
/*asks*/  

#question {
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:none;
    font-family:arial;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;    
    padding-left:9px;
    background:#fff;
    color:#000 ;
   
}
 
#question a{
    color:#000;
   
}
 

 
/*audio player container*/ 

.playercontainer {
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:0px;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:480px;
}

/*artist, song, etc.*/ 

.musicinfo {
    padding-top:7px;
    padding-left:50px;
    color:#000;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>THEMES</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://assets.tumblr.com/images/default_avatar/sphere_closed_128.png">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/rss">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unica+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://static.tumblr.com/iuw14ew/VSQma1786/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></script>


  <div id="topbar">
    <div id="title">Themes for you</div>

    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="titab home">Home</div>
      <div class="titab contact">Contact</div>
      <div class="titab submit">Submit</div>
      <div class="titab links">Links</div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="tab home">
    <div class="entries">
      <div class="post">


        <iframe width="500" height="281" id="youtube_iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LKn_3jOKCd8?feature=oembed&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=https://safe.txmblr.com&amp;wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        <p>Video example</p>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913245268/video-example">5:17 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/video-post">#video post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">


        <iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F4595620&amp;visual=true&amp;liking=false&amp;sharing=false&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;continuous_play=false&amp;origin=tumblr" frameborder="0"
          allowtransparency="true" class="soundcloud_audio_player" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
        <p>Song example</p>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913201693/song-example">5:16 pm</a>       <a href="http://soundcloud.com/rodrigovaz/johann-sebastian-bach-pachelbels-cannon-in-d-major">source</a></div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/song-post">#song post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">


        <h1>Chat example</h1><b>Someone:</b> Hello!<br><b>Somebody:</b> How are you?<br><b>Someone:</b> Good. This is an example of a chat between two people<br>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913135663/chat-example">5:14 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/chat-post">#chat post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">


        <h1><a href="http://t.umblr.com/redirect?z=http%3A%2F%2Ffr.lipsum.com%2F&amp;t=NzM2ZDBmOWE1MjkxNjE3ZWE4MTVjZWY0YjhkMmYwYzA5MzFlMTcxOSxXMUV1V2RJNg%3D%3D&amp;b=t%3Aug0c1iN6GrzkGIMg-nJ8Ww&amp;p=https%3A%2F%2Fthemesforyou.tumblr.com%2Fpost%2F162913065653%2Florem-ipsum-all-the-facts-lipsum-generator&amp;m=1">Lorem Ipsum - All the facts - Lipsum generator</a></h1>
        <p>Link example</p>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913065653/lorem-ipsum-all-the-facts-lipsum-generator">5:12 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/link-post">#link post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">


        <big><b>"This is what a quote looks like"</b></big>
        <p></p>— Source


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913036513/this-is-what-a-quote-looks-like">5:11 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/quote-post">#quote post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">


        <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/image/162913004603"><img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/cf975a46b1a6b0183ea6e5017f56271c/tumblr_oszxhlV6bZ1wuevxyo1_500.png"></a>
        <p>Photo example</p>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162913004603/photo-example">5:10 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/photo-post">#photo post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/post-example">#post example</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="post">

        <h1><big><big>Text example</big></big></h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras efficitur eget massa at mattis. Nulla ullamcorper massa ante, et bibendum sem ultricies et. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse tempus orci ex, fermentum accumsan velit pulvinar
          a. Pellentesque vehicula, felis non fermentum suscipit, sem velit scelerisque urna, eu placerat velit lectus ut metus. Duis molestie scelerisque convallis. In ornare libero ipsum, eget rhoncus velit viverra a. Maecenas facilisis tellus metus,
          ac consequat tellus tristique et. Aenean eu neque eu erat euismod euismod. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis in maximus ipsum.</p>
        <p>Nullam ac dui et augue rhoncus condimentum facilisis in orci. Aenean sit amet metus magna. Mauris eu pellentesque velit. Nullam dui risus, varius nec sem pellentesque, suscipit consequat mauris. Vivamus volutpat, mi in molestie blandit, ligula
          odio efficitur libero, ac porta leo tellus eu felis. Mauris auctor orci sagittis libero semper tristique. Praesent hendrerit purus ex, eget fermentum nulla maximus nec. Fusce nisi metus, scelerisque et mi vitae, posuere condimentum odio. Aenean
          maximus erat non commodo aliquam. Aliquam ac tincidunt metus. Integer tincidunt id sapien lobortis imperdiet. Maecenas enim sem, vehicula sit amet feugiat sit amet, ornare vitae ex. Nam vulputate volutpat quam, a dapibus justo cursus vel. Donec
          ac gravida nulla. In ultrices erat et dictum tristique.</p>


        <div class="postinfo"> <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/post/162912904188/text-example">5:07 pm</a>       </div>


        <div class="tags">
          <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/text-post">#text post</a>  <a href="https://themesforyou.tumblr.com/tagged/example-post">#example post</a>  </div>


        <div class="postnote">

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <!-- end entries-->

  </div>
  <!--end tab 1-->

  <div class="tab contact">

    <iframe class="inbox" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="no" width="350" height="260" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.tumblr.com/ask_form/themesforyou.tumblr.com"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="tab submit">
    <iframe class="inbox" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="no" width="350" height="260" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.tumblr.com/submit_form/themesforyou.tumblr.com"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="tab links">
    <div class="link">
      <div class="tilink">Title</div>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 1</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 2</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 3</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
      <div class="tilink">Title</div>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 1</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 2</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 3</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
      <div class="tilink">Title</div>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 1</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 2</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 3</a>
      <a href="/tagged/">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```